# Custom Control for Posting on the Wall(like in Facebook App)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, custom-controls

I'm searching for the Custom Control, that would provide ViewController for posting the status on the wall like in the Facebook App for iOS. Like so:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bcdsharesheet

or for posting photos

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/asfbpostcontroller

Comment: The first one is for sharing, I don't need it. Second one, I new about it, it is not exactly what I'm searching for.

Comment: Ok, how about this? http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11540372/facebook-sdk-post-on-wall-on-iphone-app

Comment: I think you didn't understand question well, I don't need to get access to FB. I need custom control to use in my own application, that is nothing to do with FB.

Comment: Oh ok. I think you right, I dont understand your question then, its hard to interpret from you question exactly what you mean.